# Use of 蓝 (Blue) in a Specific Context?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

There is a song sung by William So whose title is 《有人喜欢蓝》 (Yǒurén xǐhuan lán - There are people who like blue.)

What does 蓝 (blue) mean in this context? Is it a reference to the sky, sea, a mood, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the lyrics of 《有人喜欢蓝》. The singer refers to "blue", for example, as "the serenity at night", "the pleasure he finds in jealousy", and "the mystical excitement". I would assume that he is talking about love: no matter how difficult it is to love someone (jealousy, fear of rejection, insomnia), he falls for "you" for "some inexplicable reason" (see line 5).

有人喜欢蓝 means, poetically, “有人”（i.e. the singer）坚持自己对爱的选择。

> 有人喜欢蓝
>
> 作词：黄伟文 作曲：黄尚伟 编曲：黄尚伟
>
> 蓝是越夜越静越美丽的一种气氛 蓝是越妒越恨越快乐的一种斗争 蓝是如迷如幻却很迫真的某种兴奋 只可意会没法说　讲不出的快感
>
> 蓝是辗转反侧在午夜　想起你睡也不稳 蓝是盛着寂寞酿的酒　跟星星对饮 蓝是传来流动怨曲声音　跟你的声线甚相近 似幕调情戏　难掩盖的风韵
>
> 我不清楚根本天生喜欢那样那样蓝 还是我已对你这种色彩太习惯 世间缤纷风景好比烟花　匆匆一刹便吹散 看尽浓和澹　还只有它不散
>
> 蓝是将小小一幅天空　剪低了做你恤衫 蓝是铺开夜夜浪接浪　海水色被单 蓝是缠绵完后歇息之间　凄美的感叹在飘散 我怀疑和你　能否再多一晚

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good answer. An upvote and acceptance to get you going.

Comment: I figured it was a love song, except that my Chinese is too weak for me to be sure. But I wrote a Spanish version (my Spanish is a bit better.) http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/338/rendering-of-to-fear

Comment: Thank you! This song is rather vague and poetic. Now that I listened to it - 蓝（lan）actually sounds a lot like the English word "love" in Cantonese! I am so glad that you asked since I am learning Cantonese myself! Andy Hui and Ekin Cheng are similar to William So in style. They probably have simpler lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

I think blue in this case means the color blue, since 藍 in Chinese doesn't mean anything else.

ps: The English name of the movie 有人喜歡藍 is not "There are people who like blue." It is "Blue Valentine". http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7B9LvwT8SU